# Get-AzureRmResource showing up the deleted resources also

Tags: powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli, azure-rm, powershell-az-module

I am creating a powershell script using Azure CLI where I am using Get-AzureRmResource command to fetch all the resources in a subscription.

This command is giving the details of deleted resources also , which are not longer in Azure portal as well. How can I get only those resources which are present in the portal

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and got deleted results as you have got as below and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresource?view=azps-8.3.0#syntax):

[image]

Then I used below command and then I have only got resources which are not deleted as below:

```
Get-AzResource   | Where {$_.Name -Notlike 'failure*'} | ft
```

[image]

If you are still getting, then it might be soft deleted or not deleted, try to delete them and try the above command.

Comment: Get-AzResource   | Where {$_.Name -Notlike 'failure*'} | ft -- this command will anyway only show the resources where name does not start with "failure" and my objective is to show all the resources from the portal excluding the hard deleted ones. so this won't solve my purpose. and I am permanently deleting the resources only.

Comment: In my output all the failure ones are deleted ones so i have used this way, yeah deleting resources permanently also does work.

Comment: so in my case, the permanently deleted resources are also popping up in the output which is wrong and if the deleted resources are also showing up for you when you don't apply the explicit filter i.e.  Where {$_.Name -Notlike 'failure*'}, then the command is working wrongly for you too.